# In SSMS, are commands separated with GO guaranteed to be synchronous?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

If I execute the following script:

```
EXECUTE LongRunningSP1
GO

EXECUTE LongRunningSP2
GO
```

Assuming both procedures take several minutes, will the GO batching cause any concurrency to happen or is LongRunningSP1 guaranteed to finish before LongRunningSP2 starts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `GO` will just split your code in batches, but it won't cause any concurrency: all batches are executed one at time, in the order they appear in the code.

Answer (score 2):

LongRunningSP1 is guaranteed to finish before LongRunningSP2 with or without the GO in between; [GO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx) is a batch separator for the command processor.

It's easier to see what it does when using the command line utility SQLCMD.

```
SQLCMD
1> exec LongRunningSP1
-- nothing happens
2> exec LongRunningSP2
-- nothing happens
3> GO
-- both procs are run, first SP1, then SP2
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes!! Go will actually make it into batches to be executed. 
So it's LongRunningSP1  which gets completed first, ALWAYS!

Comment: Just so long as you haven't changed the batch separator in the options settings in management studio ...

Answer (score 0):

GO is not a Transact-SQL statement; it is a command recognized by the sqlcmd and osql utilities and SQL Server Management Studio Code editor. It is a batch terminator, it will not change the order of your query. You can however change it to whatever you want under options.

Here are a set of very simple, easy steps to customize the batch separator in SSMS:

1. Launch SSMS
2. Go to Tools –> Options
3. Click on the “Query Execution” node
4. Notice that we have an option to change the Batch Separator
5. Change the batch separator
6. Click “OK”